# Java buttons on top of graphics in a GUI issue

Tags: java, swing, button, user-interface, graphics

For my end of the year project, I'm trying to make a game which helps a person study different questions, which are shown in a GUI.  Ideally, buttons will be available for the user to press and see if their answer was correct.  I have made the basis of the GUI with the variables, the `ArrayList <String[]>` variable which will hold the questions with their answers, and tried to make buttons.

However, when I try to run the program, the buttons (I only have one in the code shown) are cut off and I am unable to place them where they properly belong.  Please help!

**Somebody please show me a solution that actually has been tested and works!  I can't seem to get it based off what has been posted for me so far!**

[image]

Here's what it looks like when I run it:

And here's all of the program's code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class EuroGUI extends JPanel {
    //Instantiate necessary variables.
    ArrayList <String[]> questions = new ArrayList <String[]>();  //Stores (Question + Answers, Correct Answer)

    int width = 1280;   //GUI Size
    int height = 720;   // ^
    int correct = 0;    //Number of correct answers
    int attempted = 0;  //Number of questions attempted
    int streak = 0;     //Number of correct answers in a row
    int points = 0;     //Points accumulated
    Font title = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 60);
    Font statsTitle = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 45);
    Font sig = new Font("Mistral", Font.PLAIN, 45);

    //Drop down options stuff
    JMenu ddMenu = new JMenu("Select an option");
    String[] dropDown = new String[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};

    String completion = "starting"; //Determines if the first time repainting

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  //Make a keyboard object to test stuff

    public static void main(String[]args){  //Main Runner
        EuroGUI g = new EuroGUI();
        g.setUpScreen();
        g.repaint();
    }

    public void setUpScreen() {  //Create the physical GUI, which paints all graphics
                                 //Used http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/377/Syllabus/8-JDBC/GUI/Progs/Layout1.java for buttons

        //Create actual GUI window and graphics.
        //Create actual GUI window and graphics.
    JFrame f = new JFrame("AP European History Study Tool");

    JPanel panelGrid = new JPanel();
    panelGrid.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    setLayout(null);

    JPanel panelBorder = new JPanel();
    panelBorder.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JButton xA = new JButton("Choice A");
    panelGrid.add(xA, "West");

    panelBorder.setLocation(500,500);
    f.getContentPane().add(panelBorder);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(width, height);
    f.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    f.add(this);

    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {  //Draws information on the GUI  (Found information on graphics 2D at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/gui_line.htm)
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) (g);

        //Draw a background box which will cover anything that was not re-painted over.
        g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
        g.fillRect (0, 1280, 0, 720);

        //Title "interface"
            //Change color back for the lines;
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            //Enable bolder lines.
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(6));

            //Create a box of lines around the title.
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(200, 0, 200, 120));
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(200, 120, 1070, 120));
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(1070, 0, 1070, 120));
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(200, 0, 1070, 0));

            //Fill in box with title with some colors :)
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillRect (200, 0, 870, 120);

            //Write title
            g2.setFont(title);
            g.setColor(Color.cyan);
            g.drawString("AP European History Study Tool", 240, 80);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("AP European History Study Tool", 238, 78);

        //Signiature on Title
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g2.setFont(sig);
            g.drawString("by My Name", 600, 120);
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.drawString("by My Name", 598, 118);

        //Statistics Bar Outline
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(1000, 170, 1000, 670));
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(1000, 170, 1280, 170));
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(1280, 170, 1280, 670));
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(1000, 670, 1280, 670));
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(6));
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect (1000, 170, 1280, 500);
            g.setColor(Color.green); //Underline
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(1055, 230, 1215, 230));
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(6));

        //Overall Score
            g2.setFont(statsTitle);
            g2.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawString("Statistics", 1055, 220);
            g2.setColor(Color.cyan);
            g.drawString(correct + "/" + attempted + " Correct", 1035, 285); 

        //Streak
            if (streak >= 3)
            {
                g2.setColor(Color.red);
                g.drawString(streak + " Streak", 1060, 340);
            }
            else{
                g2.setColor(Color.cyan);
                g.drawString(streak + " Streak", 1060, 340);
            }


        if (completion.equals("starting")){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the screenshot of the desired output?

Comment: Never use `null` layout?

Comment: I removed the null layout and it didn't change at all.  And I'm unable to add the photo because my account does not have enough reputation yet?

Comment: The image I uploaded showed sort of what I want, as long as it shows the questions and has buttons to choose answers I'm fine with anything!

Comment: I have added the screenshot to make it clear for others.

Comment: Provide ASCII art (or an image with a simple drawing) of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Answer (score 1):

This is a symptom of breaking the paint chain.

`Graphics` is a shared resources, that is, the same `Graphics` context is used to paint all the components within a paint cycle.

One of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to prepare the `Graphics` context for painting by clearing it before anything is painted to it.

So instead of...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {  //Draws information on the GUI  (Found information on graphics 2D at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/gui_line.htm)
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) (g);
```

Try using

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {  //Draws information on the GUI  (Found information on graphics 2D at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/gui_line.htm)
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) (g);
```

Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern UIs. You don't control factors like font metrics, dpi or rendering pipelines which all effect the amount of space individual components might need. Instead you should make use of appropriate layout managers and consider using compound layouts to produce more complex solutions

**Updated with example**

There are a number of things wrong, the main problem is, `panelGrid` isn't been added to anything.  The `null` layout manager is also not helping.

You're also focusing all your efforts into a single panel, which is going to make life messy.

Instead, try separating each section into its own component and focus on there individual needs, you'll find it much easier to manage in the long run.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }

    public Example() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new HeaderPane(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.add(new StatisticsPane(), BorderLayout.EAST);
                frame.add(new QuestionPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class HeaderPane extends JPanel {

        public HeaderPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
//            gbc.ipadx = 100;
            NamePane namePane = new NamePane();
            FontMetrics fm = namePane.getFontMetrics(namePane.getFont());
            add(namePane, gbc);

            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, fm.getDescent(), 0);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            gbc.ipadx = 10;
            gbc.ipady = 10;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            add(new TitlePane(), gbc);
        }

        public class ShadowLabel extends JPanel {

            private String text;
            private Color shadowColor;
            private int shadowOffset;

            public ShadowLabel(String text, Color shadowColor) {
                this.text = text;
                this.shadowColor = shadowColor;
                this.shadowOffset = 2;
            }



            public int getShadowOffset() {
                return shadowOffset;
            }

            public void setShadowOffset(int shadowOffset) {
                this.shadowOffset = shadowOffset;
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());
                return new Dimension(fm.stringWidth(getText()), fm.getHeight());
            }

            public String getText() {
                return text;
            }

            public Color getShadowColor() {
                return shadowColor;
            }

            public void setText(String text) {
                this.text = text;
                repaint();
            }

            public void setShadowColor(Color shadowColor) {
                this.shadowColor = shadowColor;
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setFont(getFont());
                FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
                int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(getText())) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2;
                g.setColor(getShadowColor());
                g.drawString(getText(), x + getShadowOffset(), y + getShadowOffset() + fm.getAscent());
                g.setColor(getForeground());
                g.drawString(getText(), x, y + fm.getAscent());
            }


        }

        public class TitlePane extends ShadowLabel {

            public TitlePane() {
                super("AP European History Study Tool", Color.CYAN);
                setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLUE));
                setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 60));
            }

        }

        public class NamePane extends ShadowLabel {

            public NamePane() {
                super("by Me", Color.WHITE);
                setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                setFont(new Font("Mistral", Font.PLAIN, 45));
                setOpaque(false);
            }

        }

    }

    public class StatisticsPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel score;
        private JLabel streak;

        public StatisticsPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE), new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4)));

            JLabel statistics = new JLabel("Statistics");
            statistics.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 45));
            statistics.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            statistics.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.GREEN), new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4)));
            add(statistics, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            score = new JLabel("0/0 correct");
            score.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            score.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 45));
            streak = new JLabel("0 streak");
            streak.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            streak.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 45));

            JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            pnl.setOpaque(false);
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            pnl.add(score, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            pnl.add(streak, gbc);

            add(pnl);

        }

    }

    public class QuestionPane extends JPanel {

        public QuestionPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            JButton xA = new JButton("Choice A");
            add(xA, gbc);
        }

    }
}
```

I would also separate the management of the data and the UI, so that the data is managed by some kind of model or models which can respond to changes in the UI and visa-versa.  This means that your UI becomes a visual representation of your data model and allows the two to decouple and work independently from each other...

Take a look [Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) for more details.  Note: Swing uses a version of this, but it's more like Model-View and Controller

You should also take a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) to see how you make better use of the ready made components available in Swing

Comment: I added the super.paintComponent(g); like you said, but now I'm unable to see the buttons at all. Could you help me by sorting out my setUpScreen method and main method so the buttons are shown with a good size near the bottom?  Thank you so much!

Comment: And I would try to find a simpler way, such as using a scanner keyboard object, but I'm sharing this with my class for them to study, and really want it to look good :)

Answer (score 0):

You did not set up your Layout properly. Might not be exactly what you are looking for but if you change from a FlowLayout to a BorderLayout it seems to fix your issue. Also you don't use panel2 anywhere in you code so you can remove it.

```
public void setUpScreen() {  //Create the physical GUI, which paints all graphics
                             //Used http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/377/Syllabus/8-JDBC/GUI/Progs/Layout1.java for buttons

    //Create actual GUI window and graphics.
    JFrame f = new JFrame("AP European History Study Tool");

    JPanel panelGrid = new JPanel();
    panelGrid.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    setLayout(null);

    JPanel panelBorder = new JPanel();
    panelBorder.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JButton xA = new JButton("Choice A");
    panelGrid.add(xA, "West");

    panelBorder.setLocation(500,500);
    f.getContentPane().add(panelBorder);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(width, height);
    f.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    f.add(this);


}
```

Comment: It looks like that fixed the issue of the button being cut off, but I'm still unable to move the location and size of the button.  I've looked at multiple posts, could you show me how I'd do that please?  Thanks!

Comment: And I'll upvote and check mark your answer once you help me, I just don't want you to miss the moving/resizing of the button :)

Comment: Where exactly do you want to put it? To easily change the size of the button you can just change the font you chose.

Comment: I'd love to put 5 buttons along the bottom part of the open space next to eachother, with a question showing above it

Comment: It's something with the Layouts try making a panel with a BorderLayout add to this panel the panel of what you have in the center or the right and then add a panel with your buttons (probably a GridLayout) to the left. I'm not sure if this will fix it but you can give it a try.

Comment: I'm really unfamiliar with using layouts, how do I specify which side (right/center/left) I want to add each layout to?

Comment: panel.add(buttonPanel, "West"); Replace West by East, North or South if needed. For this to work panel layout has to be a BorderLayout

Comment: So I revised it to the following.  But I'm not sure how to add what I have in the center or right to the border layout, since I call for it using f.add(this);  If you're not sure, thanks for the help anyways! I can just use a terminal response or something I suppose :/

Comment: I edited my post with the changes I made, and I also accidentally edited yours, so just ignore that haha

Comment: I know it is fixable by playing with the layouts but since I did not code this application this would take me a long time to figure out what goes where. You should look at the documentation for Layouts or check some tutorials to get familiar with them

Comment: Alright I'll definitely do that tomorrow!  I check marked your answer, if you think of anything let me know, and I'll let you know if I happen to figure it out. Thanks for the help!